# Chart inside chart Kendo for Angular

Tags: angular, graph, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm trying to create a graph like the one in the picture, but don't even know where to begin. Haven't used Progress Kendo charts, this is my first time. Any help will be appreciated. I'm thinking is something like a graph inside another one, but I'm not sure[In the same plane, there's multiple structure-like charts, but each for a different asset. The thing is multiple charts are using the same plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SOAj.png).

I just have generated a single graph with a single data set. But not even a bar one, a line one.

Comment: That's just a regular column chart with multiple series:  https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/column

Comment: Here is a working demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/UwAmETEF

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.